# Unexpected differences with various uses of NormFunction

Tags: evaluation, fitting

I would expect all of the following to give the same answer (`2.12467`) but only half of them give this answer. The others seem to be using the default `NormFunction:>(Norm[#,2]&)`. Can anyone explain this?

```
α = 3;
n /. FindFit[{1, 3, 9, 20}, x^n, n, x, NormFunction :> ((Null; Norm[#, α]) &)]
n /. FindFit[{1, 3, 9, 20}, x^n, n, x, NormFunction :> ((Norm[#, α]) &)]
n /. FindFit[{1, 3, 9, 20}, x^n, n, x, NormFunction :> (Norm[#, 3] &)]

Block[{α = 3},  n /. FindFit[{1, 3, 9, 20}, x^n, n, x, NormFunction :> (Norm[#, α] &)]]
With[{α = 3}, n /. FindFit[{1, 3, 9, 20}, x^n, n, x, NormFunction :> (Norm[#, α] &)]]
Module[{α = 3}, n /. FindFit[{1, 3, 9, 20}, x^n, n, x, NormFunction :> (Norm[#, α] &)]]

(* Outputs: 2.12467, 2.13284, 2.12467, 2.13284, 2.12467, 2.13284 *)
```

Comment: Actually, the last three cases can be reduced to the second and third: Block just has the effect of temporarily setting `a` to `3` therefore the expression is exactly equivalent to the second case (indeed, if executed in that order, the `Block` is even redundant because `a` already has the value `3`). The `With` replaces the `a` by the literal `3`, therefore it's exactly equivalent to the third case. And `Module` replaces `a` by a temporary variable which is set to 3, but of course the name (and life time) of the variable doesn't matter, therefore it's again equivalent to case 2.

Answer (score 9):

This must have to do with the symbolic preprocessing, happening in `FindFit`. In all cases when you get `2.13284`, this was a result of symbolic preprocessing, which was possible because the norm function could be evaluated on symbolic arguments. The subsequent result is likely explained by the mechanism described by @Searke.

But if you define your own `norm` as

```
ClearAll[norm];
norm[vec_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &), alpha_] := Norm[vec, alpha];
```

and replace `Norm` with `norm` in all your examples, you always get `2.12467`. You can gain more insight into this by using `Trace` with `TraceInternal -> True`.

Comment: In fact it seems to be enough to write `norm=Norm`, so the symbolic preprocessing must be doing something very fragile.

Comment: @LevBishop Good point. Alas, I don't have enough time right now to dig deeper into it.

Answer (score 5):

Compare your results to:

```
FindFit[{1, 3, 9, 20}, x^n, n, x, NormFunction :> ((Norm[#, thisisnotavariable]) &)]
```

When the `NormFunction` fails and is not well designed, `FindFit` just quietly chooses the 2-norm.

This is effectively what is happening in your example above.

Comment: What, in this case, makes `Norm[#, α]&` not well designed?

Comment: It's not so simple:  `FindFit[{1, 3, 9, 20}, x^n, n, x, NormFunction :> (notavariable &)]` gives a straightforward error message ("not a real number"). And why does adding a redundant compoundexpression (`Null;`) change my `NormFunction` from "not well designed" to "well designed"?